# What'sthe difference between paying attention and heeding attention?

Tags: word-difference

What's the difference between paying attention and heeding attention?

Are they interchangeable?

Comment: I've heard of someone *taking heed*, but I've never heard of anyone *heeding attention*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Heed" is a somewhat old-fashioned or literary synonym for "pay attention".

"Heed" can also be used as a noun: usually "take heed (of)", but sometimes also "pay heed (to)".

I don't recognise "heed attention".

Comment: The typical thing that is heeded are words or what someone has said, or possibly a mood, but not usually attention.